# Symfony tests how to pass depencencies to services via container

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection, phpunit

I'm writing tests for a Symfony 4.4 app and I need to mock a service named `TokenService` which is a dependency of some classes that I need to test (repositories, services), but I'm not sure how to proceed to pass some dependencies via DI :

```
 self::$container->get('App\Services\classToTest') // Not able to pass dependencies ?
```

Am I forced to instantiate the class and do something like this :

```
$classToTest = new \App\Services\classToTest($depencencyOne,$tokenMock,...)
```

Also, I need to mock only one of the dependencies, so do I have to pass all the other dependencies anyway ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `get()` from the testing service container but you can also `set()` !

I can give a real example I recently had where I needed to replace the [HttpClient](https://symfony.com/doc/current/http_client.html) with its mock implementation in some tests:

```php
// Here I replace the service with a mock implementation (a PHPUnit mock can work too)
self::getContainer()->set(HttpClientInterface::class, new MockHttpClient([
    new MockResponse('{"some":"JSON"}'),
    new MockResponse('{"other":"JSON"}'),
]));

// Here $myService will get the mock injected instead of the original HTTP Client
$myService = self::getContainer()->get(MyService::class);
```

But it should be noted that I had to make the service public to be allowed to overwrite it:

```yaml
# services.yaml
when@test:
    services:
        Symfony\Contracts\HttpClient\HttpClientInterface:
            alias: '.debug.http_client'
            public: true
```

If you don't (or can't) replace a dependency in the service container, then yes you will need to instantiate the tested service yourself and get every dependency:

```php
$myService = new MyService(
     self::getContainer()->get(RealService::class),
     $someMockDependency
);
```

If the issue comes from your own code, be sure to follow good practices to make your code easier to test (mostly **dependency injection** and **dependency inversion** principles).